# using fontface on css for custom font in webpage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good day, slight issue here, I cannot seem to implement a custom "Brandon Grotesque" font in css. I would like to know where my error is. The font is in the "fonts" folder.

[image]
[image]

CSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Brandon_reg_it';
  src: url('fonts/brandon-grotesque-light');
}

.navbar {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-family: 'Brandon_reg_it';
}
```

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give more detail on the error?

Comment: You may be missing the file extension. E.g. `'fonts/brandon-grotesque-light.otf'`

Comment: ^ I was just about to comment that.

Comment: adding .otg does not seem to turn the font into the one i want

Comment: any updates would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the full list of errors, but the big one that caught my eye was that you don't have extension in there in `css`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Brandon_reg_it';
  src: url('fonts/brandon-grotesque-light.[woff|woff2|...]'); /*Change it to whatever*/
}
```

So remove the `[...]` to the extension.

Here's a good resource: [MDN @font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)

Comment: sry the font does not seem to turn into the one i want even if i add my extention (.otf)